# Validate a string's format like a phone number?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm a newbie in C#..I'm writing a console application that accepts data,

I want to validate the data such that it must be entered in a particular format

e.g Phone number must be entered in format ' (000)-00000000-(000) '

Please how do i do that.

Comment: Check out Regular Expressions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use a regular expression for that, as zmbq stated, but that code might look something like this:

```
var regex = @"\(\d{3}\)-\d{8}-\(\d{3}\)";
var matches = Regex.Match("(123)-12345678-(123)", regex);

// this means it did in fact match the input
if (matches.Success)
```

and here is a [Rubular to prove](http://rubular.com/r/8NbZzVJKEk) the regex I provided you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but Please what if i want to change it to string

Comment: @Tijesunimi, this would work for any string that needed to match the mask. The \d means any digit and the {3} would mean three times for example.